# ¿Como puedo direccionar un carusel de bootstrap al lado contrario?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, carrusel

Hola tengo el siguiente código que es un carrusel pero no logro hacer que direcciones al lado contrario

```
<a href="https://tuhogarconsentido.com/soluciones/" id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="col-lg-3 carousel direction-right slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" >
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ asset('images/services/B2b-IMG-home.png') }}" alt="First slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ asset('images/services/Dentista-IMG-HOME.png') }}" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
```

En la documentación menciona lo siguiente:
direction: The direction in which the carousel is sliding (either "left" or "right").
All carousel events are fired at the carousel itself (i.e. at the div class="carousel").
Ya hice varias pruebas pero no logro que vaya a la derecha. Como puedo hacerlo

Comment: Qué versión de Bootstrap usas? Te refieres a tener un carousel RTL? Que corra automáticamente desde la derecha hacia la izquierda?

Comment: La version es 4, y si corre de manera automática  de derecha a izquierda pero quiero que vaya en sentido contrario

Comment: Creo que no puedes salvo que toques el código. En la documentación no da ninguna opción para modificar el sentido de desplazamiento. Lo que mencionas se refiere a los eventos provocado al usar los botones prev/next

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!

Comment: Sí, se puede, con los eventos https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/carousel/#events De igual forma en la versión 5 se menciona la tecnología RTL, aunque experimental https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/

Answer (score 0):

Parece que hay una solución. Es algo truculenta, pero funciona sin tocar el código el carrusel.

Te doy un ejemplo simple que seguro podrás adaptar si no te vale tal como está.

Primero desactivas el modo automático.

```
<div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-bs-interval="false" data-bs-ride="false">
```

Luego metes un script para que automáticamente "pulse" el botón izquierdo.

```
<script>
    setInterval(function(){ 
        document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-control-prev')[0].click()
    }, 3000)
</script>
```

Ahora cada 3 segundos se pulsará el botón izquierdo y el slide pasará de Izquerda a Derecha.

He usado el ClassName para seleccionar el botón, también puedes ponerle un id y seleccionarlo mediante getElementById. A tu gusto.
Ah, lo he probado y funciona con Bootstrap 5, pero seguro que también va con versiones anteriores.

¿Es lo que querías?

Comment: Deja lo checo, hare estos cambios. En cuanto funcione te lo notifico y palomeo tu respuesta. Gracias